# DriveResourceClient in Drive API not found

Tags: android, google-drive-api

While working with Google Drive API in Android, I found lots of contents mentioning DriveResourceClient (class or interface). However, in my Android I didn't find the same class.

I confirmed about the version mentioned in COMPILE Section of build.gradle file too, and found that it has the same version which was mentioned in those contents.

following is the dependency used in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.4.2'
```

I am building app having *minSdkVersion 23* (i.e. Android 6) and *targetSdkVersion is 26* (i.e. Android 8.0).

I guess, I am missing some settings.

Any guidance would be very helpful to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Google Play services release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_6_2017_-_version_1160), `DriveResourceClient` was only added in version `11.6.0` of Google Play services. Update your dependency if you'd like to use the new API.